# org.mule.construct.Flow: Failed to stop service: https-testFlow in mule 3

Tags: https, mule, mulesoft, mule-component

Working on HTTPS in Mule 3, While run the Project its failed to Deploy.

Error:

```
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: KeyStore must be configured for server side SSL at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig.initialise(DefaultHttpListenerConfig.java:168) ~[SE-13596-3.9.4-1.0.jar:?]
```

Log File :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUzPabl8P1ZiYIbiLIk41HKK7z76a_bE/view?usp=sharing

keystore.jks file is create by this command :

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore C:/Users/mani.thangadurai/Documents/keystore.jks -keypass mulesoft -storepass mulesoft -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA -keysize 1024 -alias mule -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 -validity 9999
```

and the project xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="0.0.0.0" port="8088" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:key-store type="jks" path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="keystore" password="keystore"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="https-testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="https working" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Please use text instead of images for logs and code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Also the screenshot doesn't show any relevant information to find the root cause of the error. Other parts of the log will probably have more details of the actual error.

Comment: Linking to external sites for files is not good either. Questions should be as self isolated as possible. This is the root cause log snippet that you could use: Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: KeyStore must be configured for server side SSL
 at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig.initialise(DefaultHttpListenerConfig.java:168) ~[SE-13596-3.9.4-1.0.jar:?]
I can't add it completely here as a comment. Please add it to the question with more lines.